# Having 2 active wired connections disables internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I recently moved in to a new apartment, and bought a network switch to put after my Verizon fios modem. Switch is connected to a board that connects to different rooms in the house.

Verizon fios -> Unifi Lite 8 PoE (Switch) -> Home network board (attached in photos) -> Rooms

Whenever I have an active connection from 2 different rooms, my internet stops working, and I get a "Network not connected" error on my router (which is connected with wire from one of these rooms).

Network module Primex 125-0986: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oDV5.jpg

Any suggestions about how to pinpoint this issue and explain it properly to my buildings management office?

Comment: Do you mean that whenever you have more than one device connected to your router the internet stops working? Does it stop for both/all devices, or just the first or last one connected? What are the device IP addresses? Can your modem hand out more than one IP address? If the modem only hands out one IP, can the router hand out IP address (does it have a DHCP server)? It sounds as though your modem is only giving 1 IP, which means that your router needs to have a DHCP server in order to create and manage IPs for the devices connected to it.

Comment: By the way, the thing you're calling a "home network board" is what we'd call a "patch panel". What is the make and model of the box you called your "Verizon FiOS modem"? What is the make and model of the box you called your "router" which is in a different room than the patch panel? If your "modem" and "router" are two separate devices, then your router needs to go in between your modem and your switch.